# Httpget removes parameters

Tags: android, url, parameters, http-get

i want to parse my serialized JSON data from the website : http://demos.brianbuikema.com/apps/soa_services/employees?format=JSON
but my result that i get back is the source code from the site: http://demos.brianbuikema.com/apps/soa_services/employees?
So somewhere my parameters format=JSON will delete. but I have no idea how en where

this is my code don't mind the log.d, it's just for me when i'm debugging debugging. `

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object


    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://demos.brianbuikema.com/apps/soa_services/employees?format=JSON");

    String result = null;
    try {
        // execute the request
        Log.d("buh", "2aa");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                            Log.d("buh", "2a");
        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release
        Log.d("buh", "2b");
        if (entity != null) {
            // A Simple Response Read
            Log.d("buh", "2c");
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.d("buh",result);
            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
     * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
     * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
     * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),
            8192);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}  `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was from the server, when requesting this URL, it removes the header JSON,
so you need to add :
        `httpget.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));` under the HttpGet

here is the full code:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    httpget.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
    //httpget.getParams().setParameter("format", "JSON");

    Log.d("z",httpget.getURI().toString());

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;

    String result = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {
            // A Simple Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            result = convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.d("z",result);
            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
    * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
    * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
    * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
    * and returned as String.
    */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is), 8192);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set name value pair. .follow this..

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
// REPLACE param [0] or one with your value of variable like _userid or etc..
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",params[0]));

        try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://thisismywebsite.com/mypage.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
        } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();     
                result=sb.toString().trim();                
        } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I hope, will works fine for you.

Comment: You use :
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet ("http://demos.brianbuikema.com/apps/soa_services/employees");
            HttpGet .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(HttpGet );

you name HttpGet  httpost but doesn't use it?
en HttpGet.setEntity doesn't exist ?

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually, I pasted some my code too that's why missed some variable naming that will looks like `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet ("http://demos.brianbuikema.com/apps/soa_services/employees");
            httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
`

Comment: no problem :) but still the  
httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
will not work. it get this error:
The method setEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity) is undefined for the type HttpGet

Comment: I got it. You need to make the HTTPPOST response rather then HTTPGet. Then, read the content of the file because you're passing your data value too..I'm pasting my full function code here. Do check that out. And implement in the same way! That will work.. Adding another answer.